# Setting up image-actions github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I have been trying to setup the github-action for [calibreapp/image-actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/image-actions), but the action doesn't seem to work properly.

I have added the yml file in .github/workflows folder, check the file [here](https://github.com/codedamn-projects/hulu-clone-project/blob/main/.github/workflows/calibreapp-image-actions.yml)
I think the problem is in the paths:

the project is hosted [here](https://github.com/codedamn-projects/hulu-clone-project)

Answer (score 0):

With the recent changes to GitHub auth of the automatically generated token very likely that your workflow is missing the correct permissions:

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write
```

Read more https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication